# Intel graphics i915 chpip (onboard graphics card) in the Kernel not working

Tags: linux, kernel, graphical-user-interface

I've got a server and that uses the i915 integrated graphics chip from Intel error

The error is:

```
    [ 3.015087] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled [ 3.029401] iwlwifi 
0000:05:00.0: base HW address: f8:94:c2:c1:56:97 [ 3.065668] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs' [ 3.065847] (NULL device ): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use 
hwmon_device_register_with_info(). [ 3.065857] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61) [ 3.066670] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0 [ 3.069180] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package [ 3.069181] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core [ 3.069182] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore [ 3.069182] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram [ 3.084532] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915]) [ 3.107600] snd_hda_codec_realtek 
hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1220: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line [ 3.107601] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) [ 3.107602] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) [ 3.107602] snd_hda_codec_realtek 
hdaudioC0D0: dig-out=0x1e/0x0 [ 3.107603] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: inputs: [ 3.107603] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Front Mic=0x19 [ 3.107604] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Rear Mic=0x18 [ 3.107604] 
snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Line=0x1a [ 3.123614] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input6 [ 3.123640] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input7 [ 3.123659] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8 [ 3.123682] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9 [ 3.123700] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10 [ 3.123719] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11 [ 3.123739] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12 [ 3.123758] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices
/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13 [ 3.123777] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14 [ 3.123794] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15 [ 3.123813] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16 [ 3.123832] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17 [ 3.769696] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 [ 3.769696] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [ 3.769698] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized [ 3.836367] [drm] RC6 on [ 3.958998] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready [ 4.168182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready [ 4.169897] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0: link is not ready [ 4.195050] IPv6: 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0: link is not ready [ 4.196786] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready [ 4.262206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready [ 4.331647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready [ 7.200614] igb 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: igb: enp6s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX [ 7.200920] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp6s0: link becomes ready [ 9.279064] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 11.817092] [drm:fwdomains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 12.034129] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized [ 12.034132] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized [ 12.034135] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11 [ 14.196678] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 14.213354] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 17.190408] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [9223372060.349595] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 24.980918] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 223.195911] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 315.386642] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 315.393116] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 727.523488] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 727.633590] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 846.002703] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 846.683353] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 846.683401] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR blitter: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 846.683440] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR media: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 847.003127] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 848.708113] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 853.291809] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 874.644506] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 874.665837] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 874.684806] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 896.386998] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 896.392183] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 896.402374] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out 
waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 896.994262] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 897.005076] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 897.113954] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 897.965779] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR blitter: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 897.965812] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 897.995920] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 903.809519] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 907.153725] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2106.895255] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2285.073290] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2315.452200] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2315.748639] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2318.584129] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2321.300881] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2325.156967] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2326.936119] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2327.767487] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2327.784489] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2328.202167] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2328.218354] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2328.269617] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2328.285153] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2330.251066] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2331.084426] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2396.465995] show_signal_msg: 16 callbacks suppressed [ 2396.465996] Web Content[2668]: segfault at 4c ip 00007f007d75b36b sp 00007ffd96587be0 error 4 in libxul.so[7f00793c3000+5805000] [ 2648.321377] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.221250] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.431670] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.502632] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.553892] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.670941] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.704575] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.720753] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.855891] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.947133] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.979820] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2660.997639] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2661.014410] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2661.031116] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2661.047825] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2661.198491] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2708.064275] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2756.800531] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2757.915006] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2774.944180] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2786.601142] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2788.595548] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2788.595570] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR blitter: timed out waiting for forcewake
 ack request. [9223374825.450361] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR media: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [9223374825.450590] [drm] GPU 
HANG: ecode 9:1:0xfffffffe, reason: Hang on bcs0, vcs0, vecs0, action: reset [ 2788.595815] [drm] GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace. [ 2788.595815] [drm] Please file a _new bug 
report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel [ 2788.595816] [drm] drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue. [ 2788.595816] [drm] The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it. [ 2788.595816] [drm] GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error [ 2788.595820] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting bcs0 after gpu hang [ 2788.595844] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting 
vcs0 after gpu hang [ 2788.595864] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting vecs0 after gpu hang [ 2788.597996] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2788.632110] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request. [ 2789.583322] 
[drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] ERROR r
```

I am running the 4.15-rc8 Kernel (for the hope that things are little more stable and less crashes).

Comment: Your copy and paste went terribly wrong somehow. Please edit your post and try it again.

Comment: This might be related to the Microcode updates that are automatically installed with Ubuntu.